# Type mismatch error - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code. But it is giving me a type mismatch error on `Excel 2013` but works fine in `Excel 2010`.

```
For Each dateRow In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("G8:G153").Cells
    cEndDate = DateValue(dateRow)
    dateArray = Split(cEndDate , "-")
    Day = CInt(dateArray(0)) 'I get the error here
    '<- more code ->
Next
```

This is working fine with no error in `Excel 2010`.

Comment: Use `Debug.Print dateArray(0)` the row before the error.

Comment: @R3uk it says `"31"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `Day` as variable, because it is a keyword (actually a function!)

And further more, it is the function that you should be using rather than reinventing the wheel! ;)

```
Dim vDay as Integer
Dim vMonth as Integer
Dim vYear as Integer
Dim dateRow as Range
Dim cEndDate as Date

For Each dateRow In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("G8:G153").Cells
    cEndDate = DateValue(dateRow.Value)
    vDay = Day(cEndDate)
    vMonth = Month(cEndDate)
    vYear = Year(cEndDate)


    '<- more code ->
Next dateRow
```